# stacked columns with pptx library of python

Tags: python, charts, powerpoint

How can I make the columns of the chart stacked when I build a .pptx report with pptx library of python?

This is an example of the output that I need:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I created the chart simply as it is the the [documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html) but I want to know what should I add to have the column stacked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact I found the solution using : **XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_STACKED**

This is the example output chart:
[image]

This is an code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
# define chart data ---------------------
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
chart_data.add_series('Series 2', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
chart_data.add_series('Series 3', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
# add chart to slide --------------------
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
slide.shapes.add_chart(
XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_STACKED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)
prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```